# Lithium: How do I change the location Connections' and similar classes look for adapters

Tags: lithium

I've been trying to get Connections to use a customised adapter located at `app/extensions/data/source/database/adapter/`. I thought extending the Connections class and replacing

```
protected static $_adapters = 'data.source';
```

with

```
protected static $_adapters = 'adapter.extension.data.source';
```

and changing the connections class used at the top of `app/config/bootstrap/connections.php` to use `app\extensions\data\Connections;`
 would be enough to get it started. However this just leads to a load of errors where the code is still trying to use the original Connections class.

Is there a simple way to achieve this, or do I have to recreate the entire set of classes from lithium/data in extensions with rewritten class references?

EDIT:
Turns out I was going about this the wrong way. After following Nate Abele's advice, `Libraries::path('adapter')` showed me where to correctly place the MySql.php file I'm trying to override ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with how named classes (i.e. services, in the abstract) are located, you want to take a look at the `Libraries` class, specifically [the `paths()` method](http://li3.me/docs/api/lithium/1.0.x/lithium/core/Libraries::paths()), which allows you to define how class paths are looked up.

You can also look at the associated definitions, like `locate()` and `$_paths`, to give you an idea of what the default configuration looks like.

Finally, note that the `Connections` class is 'special' since it defines one path dynamically, based on the supplied configuration: http://li3.me/docs/api/lithium/1.0.x/lithium/data/Connections::_class()

This should help you reconfigure how your classes are organized without extending/overriding anything. Generally you shouldn't need to do that unless you need some drastically different behavior.

Comment: Also, feel free to follow up with code examples showing what you're doing, and/or the error messages you're getting.

Comment: Hi Nate. After reading your reply and studying the Libraries::paths() docs and code I've edited my original question.